# Taxonomical and non-taxonomical relationships in ontology

Tags: taxonomy, ontology

I have studied ontologies for some time and one thing is still not clear to me.
What is the difference between taxonomical and non-taxonomical relationships in the ontology? Could you please give me some example?

Answer (score 0):

Non-taxonomic:

Foot is part of the Leg.

Earth is bigger than Mercury

Pearls before Swine

Taxonomic:

Man is a Person

Car is a Vehicle

Taxonomy is an Ontology